# Is my approach about the ML model correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, statistics

First of all, I am a newbie here and it is my first question on this platform, so I apologize for the mistakes about the format if there are any.

In my thesis study, I am trying to identify the non-normal fuel consumption of an aircraft for a specific flight by looking at the commercial aviation parameters. To achieve this, I use two separate databases; one is the actual flight data (QAR data), while the other is high-fidelity simulations (Operational Flight Plans). My strategy is to train the feed-forward ML model (I use Pytorch) with simulations (OFP) and test them with QAR data. Below is the best model result with certain ML conditions.

[image: Best Model goes here]

The above means, the trained model can predict an actual flight's fuel burn with less than %5 error for %99.3 of the flights. In the same manner, error<%3 --> %93.4 of flights,  error<%2 --> %78.9 of flights.

This is where my confusion begins.

Let's say, %0.7 of the flights burned %5 fuel less or more. How could I be sure this is not caused by the training error? If I test the model with OFP parameters and look at the model's error flight-by-flight and identify the flights with training errors (i.e. %5 more or less fuel burn), and exclude them from the first non-normal identification process, would that work? In my opinion,  this idea won't work since the training dataset will be the same as the test dataset and the model will overfit.

Do you think the above approach is correct? Is there any other option that I can stick with to overcome the training errors? Or should I accept the training errors as they are because there is nothing to do about them in this case?

Comment: in my opinion, what you ask can be answered by baseline statistics, particularly std deviation calculations. You calculate the std deviation of fuel consumption of flights and this gives you a baseline to rely upon. If training error is in that range, I dont think there is anything one can do

Comment: What is your precise goal ?
Is your goal to predict normal/simulated consumption from QAR data? (so your do not need OFP data later)
If yes, you should train with variables from QAR and target from OFP.
Then you will be able to calculate the difference between predicted target and QAR 
data, and decide if this is a normal or non normal consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: please bear in mind that I'm no expert in this kind of application.

> How could I be sure this is not caused by the training error?

You can be sure because the evaluation process is valid. Errors are expected in any ML process, what matters is to correctly estimate the expected level of error (performance evaluation).

As far as I can tell, your current approach is correct in the sense that your evaluation setup seems valid: the test set is made of actual flight data. As long as the evaluation is reliable, the way the model is trained doesn't matter. In fact the model could even be a simple heuristic with no training data: probably it wouldn't perform as well, but what matters in terms of methodology is that the performance is properly estimated.

I'm not 100% sure that I follow the process that you consider doing for cleaning up the training data. Importantly **it should not rely on the actual flight data that you use as test set**, since this would cause data leakage. As long as it doesn't, you can preprocess the dataset any way you want. But be careful that if you plan to attempt many different options for the training data and evaluate each of them, then you should use a validation set, different from the final test set (this process would be akin to parameter tuning).

Btw you could consider using a small subset of the actual flight data as validation set during the training process (I assume that you currently use some of the simulated data right?). Again if you do this make sure to use a completely independent subset as test set.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Erwan. I am afraid, I do not use a validation set because the test set is already split and available (and not too big). But, I could not completely understand how a validation dataset would help in this situation. If I pick a subset of actual flight data as a validation set how can I decide if the flight is non-normal or the difference is just caused by validation loss?

Comment: @ogulcandemirhan a validation set is used when there is a need for evaluating as part of a training process. When one tests multiple options for training a model (e.g. by selecting instances, feature selection, parameter tuning) and then chooses the best option based on evaluation, this process is a form of training and therefore the evaluation should done on some validation set. So in case you attempt multiple options for this idea of discarding some instances from the training set, the result should be evaluated against a validation set.

Comment: The question of deciding which instances are "normal" is a whole different matter, I don't have any idea about that because it's a matter of expert knowledge. From a ML perspective the only important point is to avoid using anything from the test set in order to do it.